# Searching strings in large mongodb collection (540GB / 4 billion documents)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes, flask-mongoengine

I have a very large database collection of around 540GB with 4 billion items.

The item contains various metadata but one important field "message" which is free text.

I would like to be able to query it for things like:

- the message contains "error"
- the message contains "password"
- the message ends with "an error occurred"

What is the best type of index to create, and how can I create it?

I was also wondering if anyone had example queries?

I having been reading into text indexes and wildcard text indexes but I'm not sure what is the best fit.

Comment: Please provide 1-2 sample documents

Comment: pretty much { ... metadata ... "message": "some string here which may be between 10-100 words" ... metadata } basically log messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) would be a good fit here:

```
db.mycoll.createIndex({ message: 'text' })

db.mycoll.find({ $text: { $search: 'error' } })
```